# How can I get class type from parent

Tags: python, python-2.7, tastypie

I have a parent class `BaseResource` in which I define a behavior that should be common to all child. I am overwriting `ModelResource.update_in_place` which is defined in some django-tastypie model.

```py
class BaseResource(ModelResource):

    def update_in_place(self, ...):
        ...
        return super(ChildResource, self).update_in_place(...)
```

Now I have `Child1Resource`, `Child2Resource` which both inherit from `BaseResource`. How can I get the type of the child resource inside of the parent ?

I've tried `self.__class__()`, but I get `must be type, not Child1Resource`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need `self.__class__`, not `self.__class__()` (the parens are the call operator, so the later returns a `self.__class__` instance, not the class itself.

But anyway: that's *not* how to use `super()`, you really want to pass `BaseResource` as the first argument here - the whole point being to pass the class where the method is defined, not the class on which the method is called (which would be pointless since it can be inspected using `self.__class__`).

Comment: But why isn't it default ? Since first parameter should *always* the `self` name, why do we have to specify it ?

Comment: @MathieuMarques: [It is in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/).  Yet another reason to upgrade.

Comment: @MathieuMarques: the first parameter should always be _the class in which `super()` is called_ - but I assume you mean the second parameter ? If yes, read the doc for `super()`: this can be `None`, an instance or a class (for classmethods). To work correctly (ie: ensure calls of all 'super' methods in the proper order), `super` needs to know both the class or instance on which the method has been invoked _and_ the class in which `super` is called. Python2's implementation solved it the simplest, explicit, but not DRY way, Python3 improved it to make it DRYer.